# What do these instructions mean? (Disassembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly, objdump

I almost sure `ebp+0x8` points to a string (the program actually asks thru a prompt for it, but I am not sure where it's stored). What's the general idea of the lines? Why add 1 to the 32-bit portion of ebp+8?

```
 mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [eax]
 mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x11],al
 add    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x1
 mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [eax]
 test   al,al
```

Comment: It's apparently testing whether the string is just a single character, and copies the first character to `ebp-0x11`. The `+1` is part of the `if (string[1] == 0)` condition which is checking the terminating zero.

Comment: That's some seriously braindead code.  It's a debug / unoptimized build, right?  It's weird for you to have that but not the source.  Reasonable code would do `mov edx, [ebp+8]` / `movzx eax, byte ptr [edx+1]` / `test al,al`.  (I left out copying the first byte to a local array at `[ebp-0x11]` since this snipped doesn't use that.  If the copy isn't needed, even `cmp byte ptr [edx+1], 0` would work.  For code-size, using `movsb` or `lodsb` would work.

Answer (score 2):

`EBP` register is use for your functions variables.

i think `EBP + 0x8` is your first function argument. and `add DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x1` is some thing like this:

```
proc01(char *c01){
''''
c01++;//add DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x1
...
}
```

Comment: As a side note about "NOT EBP", EBP is also sometimes used as a general purpose register, especially in the case of FPO optimization.

Comment: @Amir Please do correct the syntactical errors in your answer!

Comment: @SepRoland I compiled my code in code-blocks with mingw compiler and it worked fine with no error.

Comment: The syntactical errors are in the Assembly instructions. You've left out some square brackets!

Comment: @SepRoland fixed it.

Comment: Still missing one in the second line of text.